# Spring Boot stops after start immediately

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring boot application stops after starting.
I've generated project with https://start.spring.io , but this happens, when i'm following instructions from https://spring.io/quickstart

```
> Task :bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.4)

2022-03-18 22:29:09.667  INFO 14205 --- [           main] com.hidk.HidPigeon.HidPigeonApplication  : Starting HidPigeonApplication using Java 17.0.2 on ABOBUS.lan with PID 14205 (/Users/laptevaleksander/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Projects/HidPigeon/build/classes/java/main started by laptevaleksander in /Users/laptevaleksander/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Projects/HidPigeon)
2022-03-18 22:29:09.669  INFO 14205 --- [           main] com.hidk.HidPigeon.HidPigeonApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-18 22:29:10.250  INFO 14205 --- [           main] com.hidk.HidPigeon.HidPigeonApplication  : Started HidPigeonApplication in 1.018 seconds (JVM running for 1.373)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is started successfully, there is no errors, the log indicate that :

```
main] com.hidk.HidPigeon.HidPigeonApplication  : Started HidPigeonApplication in 1.018 seconds (JVM running for 1.373)
```

**Edit :** you can add the `spring-boot-starter-web` as below and you project will start as expected:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**result :**

[image]

you can test access to the server from this url: `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: But then it stops immediately

Comment: @Hid-K because your project does do nothing, and does not have the `spring-boot-starter-web` you can add it in your project and it will work's and lunch the server you can see my answer's edit

Comment: @Hid-K see the edit

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add this into `build.gradle`:

```
implementation group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation'
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime'
```